# Array of LinkedList with multiple values in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, circular-list

I'm trying to create an array or ArrayList which holds the 3 separate linked lists.

Let's say I have an Array of Departments (Sales, Media, Crew)
Each element is a circular linked link of name, title, id, and pay rate.

Example:

```
Sales:
Node 1: Name Title       ID    Payrate
        Mary Salesperson 1378 25.46

Node 2: Name Title       ID    Payrate
        Mary Salesperson 1364 20.13

Media:
Node 1: Name Title       ID    Payrate
        John Designer    563   30.50

Node 2: Name  Title       ID    Payrate
        Chris Designer    586   563
```

I want to be able to retrieve the nodes in that specific linked list like Departments(Sales).next, etc. This is my current code:

```java
public class Circle{
    
    public static class CircularLinkedList {
        private Node head = null;
        private Node tail = null;
        private int length;
    
        class Node{
            private Node next;
            private String deptNameIn;
            private String empNameIn;
            private String title;
            private int id;
            private float payrate;
            
            public Node(String deptNameIn, String empNameIn, String title, int id, float payrate) {
                this.deptNameIn = deptNameIn;
                this.empNameIn = empNameIn;
                this.title = title;
                this.id = id;
                this.payrate = payrate;
            }
        }

        public CircularLinkedList() {
            length = 0;
        }
        
        public void insertNodeRight(String deptNameIn, String empNameIn, String title, int id, float payrate) {
            Node newNode = new Node(deptNameIn, empNameIn, title, id, payrate);
            
            if (head == null) {
                head = newNode;
            } else {
                tail.next = newNode;
            }
            tail = newNode;
            tail.next = head;
            
            length++;
            
        }
        
        public static CircularLinkedList createCircularLinkedList() {
            CircularLinkedList cll = new CircularLinkedList();
        
            cll.insertNodeRight("Sales", "Mary", "Sales_person", 568, (float) 12.50);
            cll.insertNodeRight("Sales", "Mary", "Sales_person", 589, (float) 25);
            cll.insertNodeRight("Sales", "Vallerie", "Manager", 123, (float) 30);
            
            return cll;
        }

   }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CircularLinkedList cll = CircularLinkedList.createCircularLinkedList();
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Also two more sidenotes, I can currently insert from the rightmost, but how can I insert from the leftmost. Also, how can I delete a node? Everything I've seen online shows deleting a node with only one value, but I have multiple values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> circular linked link of name, title, id, and pay rate.

> Also, how can I delete a node? Everything I've seen online shows deleting a node with only one value, but I have multiple values.

No, you don't. You have a circular linked list of **Node objects**. Your linked list consists of **Node objects** - not 'multiple values'.

Once you can wrap your head around that, you'll see all the thousands of blog posts and tutorials you find when you search the web for 'how to write a linked list in java' apply here just the same.

### How do I insert an new node at the start?

Well, think about it. After you're doing adding a new node 'at the front', `head` needs to be pointing at this new node, and the new node's `next` needs to be pointing at what used to be head.

Also, of course, length must be increased. It's the exact same code as what you already have for `insertNodeRight`, just, flip head/tail and next/prev around.

Deleting nodes is, again, the same principle. Think about what the head/tail pointers of your linked list start out as, and what they need to become, and what the next/prev pointers in your list start out as, and what they need to become. Sketch it out on paper if you like.

Once you've figured it out, just write code that does what you sketched; for exercises like this, it's trivial, and your `insertNodeRight` code shows the way.

Comment: Well, it's not so much 'delete the head', as 'make head point at something else (the thing that used to be pointed at by head.next). The state of the linked list is defined entirely by head/tail, and the next/prev nodes of everything within it, all operations on a linked list can be expressed in terms of that. Deletion, addition - it's all just assigning things to head/tail and next/prev fields.